# Compact way to assign nested property to root of a new object

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if there's a compact way to pull a property from an object, and then assign said property to the root of a new object, using the same property name.

Basically, I'd like to do the following without needing the first line:

```
const targetProp = someObj.data.targetProp;  
const newObj = {  
     targetProp  
}
```

What I'd imagine it might look like:

```
const newObj = {
     [someObj.data.targetProp]
}
```

Where newObj would then have a property named 'targetProp', with the value of someObj.data.targetProp

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an extra variable:

```
const newObj = {
  targetProp: someObj.data.targetProp
}
```

Destructuring is an option, which will reduce the size of the original code, but that requires keeping a first line:

```
const { targetProp } = someObj.data;
const newObj = { targetProp };
```

I don't think there's anything better than these two options.

Comment: Thanks, either of these options are fine. It does kinda feel like there should be a more 'nodejs' way of doing things when mapping multiple complex objects to a single simple object though.

Comment: I'm sure there are library methods that can achieve it too, but then you're importing a big library, which means a few hundred or more extra lines instead of a single extra line